# Add objects dinamically to an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am wondering if there is a way to dynamically add objects to an array of objects based on a value? For example, I have an array of objects:

```
[
    {category:A, num:5}, 
    {category:B, num:2}
]
```

I want to create another array of objects where objects would be the same, but repeated based on the value of num (so 5 times for category A and 2 times for category B) :

```
[
    {category:A, num:5, repeated:1},
    {category:A, num:5, repeated:2},
    {category:A, num:5, repeated:3},
    {category:A, num:5, repeated:4},
    {category:A, num:5, repeated:5},
    {category:B, num:2, repeated:1}, 
    {category:B, num:2, repeated:2}
]
```

I have tried map, forEach, for loop, but nothing worked.
I am quite new to javascript, how some one could help!

Comment: Are you confusing `java` with `javascript`?

Comment: This Wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language) states: _Not to be confused with JavaScript._

Comment: Ohh, just a mistake in the tag, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a combination of `flatMap` and `map`:

```js
var input = [
    {category:"A", num:5}, 
    {category:"B", num:2}
] ;

var result = input.flatMap(e => [...new Array(e.num)].map( (x,i) => ({
    category:e.category,
    num: e.num,
    repeated: i+1
})));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) -

```js
const repeat = ({ num = 0, ...t }) =>
  num === 0
    ? []
    : [ ...repeat({ ...t, num: num - 1 }), { ...t, num, repeated: num } ]

const input = 
  [ { category: "A", num: 5}, { category: "B", num: 2 } ]
  
const output =
  input.flatMap(repeat)
  
console.log(output)
```

Output -

```js
[
  { category: "A", num: 1, repeated: 1 },
  { category: "A", num: 2, repeated: 2 },
  { category: "A", num: 3, repeated: 3 },
  { category: "A", num: 4, repeated: 4 },
  { category: "A", num: 5, repeated: 5 },
  { category: "B", num: 1, repeated: 1 },
  { category: "B", num: 2, repeated: 2 }
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Didnt know about flatMap, very useful.